# Is "obtain from X a Y" correct in grammar?

Tags: grammar

I'm reading [this document](https://www.javassist.org/tutorial/tutorial.html), and quote

> To modify the definition of a class, the users must first obtain from a ClassPool object a reference to a CtClass object representing that class.
>
> get() in ClassPool is used for this purpose.

"obtain from a ClassPool object a reference" does not seems to be correct, shouldn't it be "obtain a reference from a ClassPool object" instead?

Comment: You can move prepositional phrases around quite a bit without making a sentence ungrammatical.

Comment: It's grammatical, but "I received from John a letter." sounds like it belongs in a poem. The device is far more natural with weighty direct objects: "I received from the solicitor a letter explaining why there had been such a delay in the processing of the will." **So the correct choice here.**

Comment: users must first obtain a reference to a CtClass object representing the class from a ClassPool object: Subject Verb Object. You don't need to say "the users". Just users is fine. It's a general statement.

Comment: If it was only _a reference_, then the order you suggest would indeed be better. But since it's _a reference to a CtClass object representing that class_ that needs to interrupt the phrase, it's better to move that to the end and get the _from_ phrase out of the way first; otherwise it's too long a time between _obtain_ and _from_.

Comment: Personally, if the order is reversed, I would tend to insert parenthethical commas around 'from X' giving, for instance: "I received, from John, a letter". Without the commas the structure seems clumsy to me.

Comment: The quote is written in the style quite common in this kind of technical, mathematical writing.  If one's conceptual focus is at least 50% on the input, this word order feels natural to me based on my study and reading in math and computer science.